# how to plot data in excel for three columns on of which is a distinguishing factor?

Tags: excel

Say if I have a data in the following format

[image]

How can I create an XL graph which gives me the Rating in a Subject over time, the lines should be on the same graph ? I tried "Scatter with smooth lines and markers" but it did not bifurcate "A" and "B"

[image]

Comment: If you expect to do a lot of this type of analysis, look into software called JMP. It "excels" at making graphs the way you describe. Pricey though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split out the Subjects.
Possibly a Pivot Chart will automate what you want to do.

- Date --> Axis
- Subject --> Legend(Series)
- Rating --> Values

[image]

Comment: I tried your approach and it worked for me, but didnt give me correct representation with Stacked lines, so I instead used normal lines.

Comment: @userx Glad to help. There are all kinds of options for different representations, depending on what you require. I just picked one at random. Happened to be "Line with Markers"

Comment: @userx, I think "Stacked" means the lines are added together. For example, if Ron's graph used stacked for 15-JAN data point, then Subject A will be at Y=1, and Subject B will be at Y=3 (1+2). That's not what you want, which is why normal lines worked better for you.